# How to Make a Dropdown Menu go up When There Isn't Enough Room on the Page - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to make my dropdown menu go up when there isn't enough room on the page to see it completely.  I'm using HTML, Javascript, CSS, and JQuery only.

Thank you for the help.

-Lynn

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear what you're looking for, but I'm going to assume you want to modify the position of your drop downs when there isn't enough place on the screen. Your best bet would be to have a check in your javascript to see if your drop down (ie. it's height) is bigger than the window's height. If it's not, don't worry about it (assuming the position is correct). If it's bigger, set a new position to the drop down (assuming it's on absolute positioning, depending on how high you want it, it could be as simple as setting the top attribute to 0. This should be executed every time the document is loaded.

Personally it's best to avoid this situation completely, a drop down should never reach, let alone surpass the dimensions of the website.It negatively affects the UX of your website.

**EDIT :** Based on more info, here is what I would do based on what I understand of your problem. Usually the drop downs are styled in absolute positioning, though to find out exactly where to position them, it's always *relative* to your principal navigation (where your drop downs will drop down from). So knowing this, I would emulate this logic in a jquery/js script. Here is the high-level logic:

```
$(<your main navigation's section>).hover(function(){
//logic for hover in
    <show drop down (opacity:1 or display:block)>
    if(menu position is greater or equal to 50% of screen){ //this means that menu is located in bottom of screen
    <display drop down below navigation>
    }else{ //menu position is less than 50$ of screen (menu is located in top half of screen
    <display drop down above navigation>
    }
}, function(){
//logic for hover out
});
```

Your logic for displaying your drop down is nothing more than a simple jquery call to display the drop down container (by redefining the opacity or display argument of the container's style). To know where to place your drop down, here is your logic:

- if **above** your main navigation, get the y-position of your main-navigation and subtract your drop down's height (retrieve all these values with jquery/js). Give or take an offset that would want between your drop down and your main-nav, and you have the absolute y-position of your drop down. the absolute x-position will be relative to the x-position of the  button being hovered by the user in the main-nav, offsetted depending on how your want your drop down be positionned relative to its *parent* menu item.
- if **below** your main navigation, the calculations are reversed. I'll let you this one to you, as a little playing won't hurt :)

When i mentionned earlier that even though the drop down is positionned: absolute, but in relality the measurements are truly relative to the main navigation, this is especially true to you since your positionning of your main navigation and your drop downs are all dynamic, meaning that a static position wouldn't work in this case.

I've given your the logic behind the code, let me know if you don't understand what I'm trying to explain.

Pat

Comment: I'm assuming that the page itself is bigger than the drop-down.  Let me be more specific.  When the drop-down shows up on the bottom of the page, I want the drop-down to go up instead of down.  When the drop-down shows up on the top of the page, I want the drop-down to go down.  This is all relative to scrolling, of course, so the drop-down may be in both the bottom of the page and the top of the page on one load.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, your whole navigation is not necessarily at the top of your site, as is usual. For the purpose of this problem, let's assume your navigation is in the middle of your document, which is twice as big as your screen (so this would allow you to interact with your navigation in every possible positions (nav is at top of page, middle of page, bottom of page). Let me edit my answer and give you a second solution-